# Beautiful Soup finds elements that don't exist in the html

Tags: python, twitter, beautifulsoup

I am using a library called [twitterscraper](https://github.com/taspinar/twitterscraper) which scrapes tweets from any given url. I gave it the url of a tweet reply and it successfully scraped the tweets displayed on the page. (except the tweet of the url itself but i will already have that tweet). The problem is that i cant find any of the elements that it has scraped from the response html in the html itself while debugging. I can't find the tweet contents when i search for them either. The tweets simply aren't there.

This is where it gets the response :

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADER, proxies={"http": proxy}, timeout=timeout)
### some code
html = response.text
```

Calls from_html:
`tweets = list(Tweet.from_html(html))`

bs4 `find_all` called and the tweets parsed

```
def from_html(cls, html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml") #no li element with js-stream-item class found when i looked through the html.
        tweets = soup.find_all('li', 'js-stream-item') #but it still finds the li elements with tweets in them?
        if tweets:
            for tweet in tweets:
                try:
                    yield cls.from_soup(tweet)
                except AttributeError:
                    pass  
                except TypeError:
                    pass
```

How is this happening?

I copied the value of html variable in vscode while debugging and searched through it. Link to find_all method of bs4: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#find-all. Link to the reply url - https://twitter.com/renderwonk/status/1290793272353239040

The function provided to scrape a url( made one change in the first line which is commented out. instead of giving the query i pass the url itself) :

```
def query_single_page(query, lang, pos, retry=50, from_user=False, timeout=60, use_proxy=True):
    """
    Returns tweets from the given URL.

    :param query: The query parameter of the query url
    :param lang: The language parameter of the query url
    :param pos: The query url parameter that determines where to start looking
    :param retry: Number of retries if something goes wrong.
    :return: The list of tweets, the pos argument for getting the next page.
    """
    #url = get_query_url(query, lang, pos, from_user)
    url = query
    logger.info('Scraping tweets from {}'.format(url))

    try:
        if use_proxy:
            proxy = next(proxy_pool)
            logger.info('Using proxy {}'.format(proxy))
            response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADER, proxies={"http": proxy}, timeout=timeout)
        else:
            print('not using proxy')
            response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADER, timeout=timeout)
        if pos is None:  # html response
            html = response.text or ''
            json_resp = None
        else:
            html = ''
            try:
                json_resp = response.json()
                html = json_resp['items_html'] or ''
            except (ValueError, KeyError) as e:
                logger.exception('Failed to parse JSON while requesting "{}"'.format(url))

        tweets = list(Tweet.from_html(html))

        if not tweets:
            try:
                if json_resp:
                    pos = json_resp['min_position']
                    has_more_items = json_resp['has_more_items']
                    if not has_more_items:
                        logger.info("Twitter returned : 'has_more_items' ")
                        return [], None
                else:
                    pos = None
            except:
                pass
            if retry > 0:
                logger.info('Retrying... (Attempts left: {})'.format(retry))
                return query_single_page(query, lang, pos, retry - 1, from_user, use_proxy=use_proxy)
            else:
                return [], pos

        if json_resp:
            return tweets, urllib.parse.quote(json_resp['min_position'])
        if from_user:
            return tweets, tweets[-1].tweet_id
        return tweets, "TWEET-{}-{}".format(tweets[-1].tweet_id, tweets[0].tweet_id)

    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        logger.exception('HTTPError {} while requesting "{}"'.format(
            e, url))
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        logger.exception('ConnectionError {} while requesting "{}"'.format(
            e, url))
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
        logger.exception('TimeOut {} while requesting "{}"'.format(
            e, url))
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        logger.exception('Failed to parse JSON "{}" while requesting "{}".'.format(
            e, url))

    if retry > 0:
        logger.info('Retrying... (Attempts left: {})'.format(retry))
        return query_single_page(query, lang, pos, retry - 1, use_proxy=use_proxy)

    logger.error('Giving up.')
    return [], None
```

The result of `find_all` call in the method `from_html`

[image]

The html from which bs4 found the above elements. i copied it while debugging:
https://codeshare.io/ad8qNe
(copy to an editor and use word wrap)

Does this have something to do with javascript?

Comment: Post the link of the twitter reply

Comment: Can you post the code of `twitterscraper` and the result you got?

Comment: ok i posted the function provided for scraping, the html response and the result of the bs4 find_all

Answer (score 2):

Take a closer look at any of the HTTP GET requests:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADER, proxies={"http": proxy}, timeout=timeout)
```

whether or not we're using proxies is not so important. What's critical in this case are the headers. It says `headers=HEADER`, so what is `HEADER`? Scroll to the top of `query.py`:

```
HEADER = {'User-Agent': random.choice(HEADERS_LIST), 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
```

In this case, `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'` is what's critical here. The response will still be HTML it seems, but the content you were looking for will be embedded inside it.

EDIT - Here is how you can do it yourself without twitterscraper (it does the same thing basically):

```
def main():

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = "https://twitter.com/renderwonk/status/1290793272353239040"

    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    for li in soup.find_all("li", {"class": "js-stream-item"}):
        tweet_div = li.find("div", {"class": "tweet"})
        text = tweet_div.find("p", {"class": "tweet-text"}).get_text()
        print(f"{''.center(32, '-')}\n{text}\n{''.center(32, '-')}\n")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: so bs4 fetches some link embedded in the html string?

Comment: @spatial Nope, the entire contents of the tweets from the given URL are in the response. Look at `Tweet.from_soup` to see how they are parsing it.

Comment: But i cant find them in the html string. ```Tweet.from_soup``` parses them alright, but thats after bs4 finds the elements. And i just cant find them in the same html string.